Rocket.chat and "rejected credentials"
I am experiencing an issue with logging into the Rocket.Chat mobile app. My setup involves IIS on Windows Server acting as a reverse proxy to Rocket.Chat, which is running in Docker on a Linux instance hosted on Hyper-V.
My Setup:

Windows Server with IIS and URL Rewrite enabled
Hyper-V hosting a Linux instance running Docker with Rocket.Chat on port 3000
IIS is configured to forward connections from https://example.com to Rocket.Chat.
SLL is generated by Let's encrypt and added to IIS binding

The web client works perfectly fine, and WebSocket connections are functioning correctly. However, the Rocket.Chat mobile app throws an error saying "credentials rejected" when trying to log in. I have verified that the credentials are correct.
Here is my current web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>    
                <rule name="RedirectHTTPtoHTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyToRocketChat" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://10.10.0.8:3000/{R:0}" />
                </rule>                
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

What I've Tried:

WebSockets are working fine, both in the browser client and in tests.
I’ve confirmed that IIS forwards requests correctly to Rocket.Chat via the reverse proxy.
Verified the mobile app credentials work fine when logging in through the web client.

My Questions:

Has anyone else encountered the "credentials rejected" issue with the Rocket.Chat mobile app when using IIS as a reverse proxy?
Could there be something in the web.config or IIS setup that is interfering with how the mobile app authenticates?
Are there additional IIS configurations or Rocket.Chat settings that need to be checked for mobile login?

